# Logic behind dividing with negative numbers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Might be dumb question but I can't figure it out. If you have a positive number x then halve or divide it in any way you end up with a number smaller than x. Makes sense because youre splitting the number in however many equal bits.

But if its negative then its different. Eg if a negative number (-x) is divided or split then the result is a bigger number. How is this possible? With numbers :

-4/2 = -2 but -2 > -4. How can you divide a number and end up with a bigger one?

Also if you divide by a negative number then you end up with a positive, why? :

-4/-2 = 2 but you divided by a negative number.... how is the result positive. I assume its because you divided with a number less than 1 hence resulting in a bigger number (1/0.1 = 10) but I have this feeling that this logic is wrong. Can someone explain please? Thanks.

Comment: Consistency of arithmetical operations: if $M \times (-a)=n$, then $M = \dfrac {n}{(-a)}$

Comment: If I owe $100$, which we can represent as having $-100$ and someone assumes half my debt, then I have $-50$, and obviously, my financial situation has improved.

Comment: "*Makes sense because youre splitting the number in however many equal bits*"  I strongly encourage you to grow past this limited view of how arithmetic works.  That is a good way to introduce division to a child.  That is not a good way to view division as an adult.  Staying with that restrictive idea of what division is leads to this type of confusion with negative numbers and dividing by non-integers... for instance $\frac{3}{\sqrt{2}}$ you can't "split" $3$ into "$\sqrt{2}$ number of parts"

Comment: If you don't think that $-4/-2 = 2$, then how many "negative twos" do you think it takes to make "negative four"?

Comment: As for "*I assume its because you divided with a number less than 1 hence resulting in a bigger number*"  Consider $\dfrac{4}{-2}=-2<4$

Comment: Of possible interest is my answer to [Was the idea that the result of division of positive number by negative number should be negative ever been controversial?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/12817/264)

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two different ways to compare two numbers.

The first is by their position on the real number line. In that case
$$\text{$0 < 5 < 10 \quad$ and $\quad -10 < -5 < 0$.}$$

The second is by their magnitudes, (their absolute values or their distance from the point with ordinate $0$ on the number line.). In that case

$$0 < |\pm 5| < |\pm 10|$$